# Bot not connecting to Telegram

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram

I am trying to create a telegram bot with node js and I get this error every time.

```
RequestError: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at new RequestError (C:\Users\FBPIDI\Desktop\TDB\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:14:15)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\FBPIDI\Desktop\TDB\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\FBPIDI\Desktop\TDB\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:496:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28) {
  code: 'EFATAL'
}
```

I tried a vpn(psiphon) because my country temporarily blocked Telegram but it didn't help

Here is my code

```
const telegrambot = require("node-telegram-bot-api");
require("dotenv").config();
const token = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;
const bot = new telegrambot(token, {polling:true});
bot.on("message",(msg) => {
    if(msg.text === "hi") {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id,`hello there, ${msg.chat.first_name}`);
    }
});
bot.on("polling_error", (msg) => console.log(msg));
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem Just solved it by using Nord vpn.